# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while integrating MuPDF jar

Tags: android, mupdf

I am trying to integrate the MuPDF jar in my project but after integrating and running my app I'm getting the above exception. These are my crash logs in the logcat:

```
07-26 16:26:18.608: W/dalvikvm(27233): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/artifex/mupdfdemo/MuPDFCore;

07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.openFile(MuPDFActivity.java:209)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity.onCreate(MuPDFActivity.java:306)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mupdf: findLibrary returned null
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFCore.<clinit>(MuPDFCore.java:14)
07-26 16:11:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(25410):    ... 15 more
```

I have put the mupdf_4.jar in my libs folder and set it in the Java Build Path as well. Could you please let me know how to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: To use mupdf android and integrate it to your android application. You need to compile your project while mupdf android library project is also opened on your IDE (eclipse?), and configure it as library of your project. Did you did that?